# Timer Delay method for Creating Stop Watch in Java

Tags: java, timer

Hi I am trying to create a StopWatch app for one of the project questions in the Java Foundations Textbook. So far I have written this code:

```
package StopWatch;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StopWatchPanel extends JPanel{
    private JPanel userPanel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel timeDisplay = new JLabel("00:00:00", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    private JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
    private JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    private Timer refreshRate = new Timer(1, new ActionListen());
    private int milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours;

    public StopWatchPanel(){
        // user panel settings
        userPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        userPanel.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 255));

        // add listeners
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListen());
        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListen());
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListen());

        // component setting
        timeDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 50));

        // add components
        userPanel.add(timeDisplay);
        userPanel.add(startButton);
        userPanel.add(stopButton);
        userPanel.add(resetButton);

        // add to main frame
        add(userPanel);
    }

    private int milsec(){
        if(milliseconds > 1000){
            milliseconds = 0;
            seconds++;
        }
        return milliseconds++;
    }

    private int sec(){
        if(seconds > 59){
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
        }
        return seconds;
    }

    private int min(){
        if(minutes > 59){
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
        return minutes;
    }

    private int hrs(){
        if(hours > 23){
            hours = 0;
        }
        return hours;
    }


    private class ActionListen implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource().equals(startButton)){
                refreshRate.start();
            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(refreshRate)){
                timeDisplay.setText(sec()+":"+milsec());
            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(stopButton)){
                refreshRate.stop();
            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(resetButton)){
                timeDisplay.setText("00:00:00");
                milliseconds = 0;
                seconds = 0;
                minutes = 0;
                hours = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it works if i set the delay on the timer to 1000ms therefore showing seconds (if i exclude the milsec method) but i want to display milliseconds as well. So I put delay to 1ms so that after each 1ms, it will setText to current count of second (sec method). 
But for some reason this doesnt work because the numbers add up too slowly considering that 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The delay of 1 ms means that the timer will generate events every 1 millisecond. The events are then dispatched to the event dispatch thread, which introduces a delay (since there's other code also running on the event dispatch thread), so the actual interval between the calls to actionPerformed() is likely to be larger than 1 ms.

If you need your clock to be precise, you need to measure the exact elapsed time between calls (using, for example, the `System.currentTimeMillis()` method), rather than increment the time by 1 ms on every call.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the timeliness of the output by varying the millisecond interval. Instead of 1ms, you can try 10, 20 or 50ms interval. The code below uses 100ms.

```
package StopWatch;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StopWatchPanel extends JPanel {
    private JPanel userPanel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel timeDisplay = new JLabel("00:00:00", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    private JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
    private JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    private Timer refreshRate = new Timer(100, new ActionListen());
    private int milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours;

    public StopWatchPanel(){
        // user panel settings
        userPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        userPanel.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 255));

        // add listeners
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListen());
        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListen());
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListen());

        // component setting
        timeDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 50));

        // add components
        userPanel.add(timeDisplay);
        userPanel.add(startButton);
        userPanel.add(stopButton);
        userPanel.add(resetButton);

        // add to main frame
        add(userPanel);
    }

    private int milsec(){
        milliseconds+=100;
        if(milliseconds >= 1000){
            milliseconds = 0;
            seconds++;
        }
        return milliseconds;
    }

    private int sec(){
        if(seconds > 59){
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
        }
        return seconds;
    }

    private int min(){
        if(minutes > 59){
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
        return minutes;
    }

    private int hrs(){
        if(hours > 23){
            hours = 0;
        }
        return hours;
    }


    private class ActionListen implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource().equals(startButton)){
                refreshRate.start();
            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(refreshRate)){
                int tms = milsec();
                int tsec = sec();
                int tmin = min();
                int thr = hrs();

                timeDisplay.setText(thr + ":" +tmin+ ":" +tsec+ "." +tms/100);
            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(stopButton)){
                refreshRate.stop();
            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(resetButton)){
                timeDisplay.setText("00:00:00");
                milliseconds = 0;
                seconds = 0;
                minutes = 0;
                hours = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the original code was primarily made for demo purposes and does not concern too much on the accurateness of the time. If you want a more realtime output, you will need to try a different approach. In such case you may use the System.currentTimeMillis() as pointed out by the other answer.